# Specified number is invalid error in sql query

Tags: mysql, sql

sql query is giving error **number is invalid**

Query:-

```
select st.id ,st.name from student st 
inner join course co on st.COURSE_FK = co.course_id 
where(st.id="DV001" and co.course_id="1001");




Student table :-
   id(String)
   name(String)
   
  course :-
   course_id(String)
```

Comment: what are :param1 and :param2?

Comment: Are you running this exact code from Workbench?  It won't work.  If this is a PHP prepared statement of some kind, please include the full PHP code.

Comment: I am runnig on oracle sql developer which can take param input on run time  though  i have updated value of param1 and param2 .

Comment: Just a guess. st.id is defined as int?

Comment: Replace double quotes with single quotes.

Comment: *sql query is giving error number is invalid* Show complete and unchanged error message.

Comment: if i have to guess the error is related to how you pass parameters to the prepared statement. You edited the question removing the parametrized query but with directly input it won't happen

Comment: Your table descriptions and query are not related.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Student Table**

```
CREATE TABLE `student` (
  `id` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `COURSE_FK` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `fk_student_1_idx` (`COURSE_FK`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_student_1` FOREIGN KEY (`COURSE_FK`) REFERENCES `course` (`course_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;
```

---

**Course Table**

```
CREATE TABLE `course` (
  `id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `course_id` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `course_id_UNIQUE` (`course_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;
```

---

**Data**

```
INSERT INTO `test`.`course` (`id`, `name`, `course_id`) VALUES (NULL, 'C1', 'C1');
INSERT INTO `test`.`course` (`id`, `name`, `course_id`) VALUES (NULL, 'C2', 'C2');
INSERT INTO `test`.`student` (`id`, `name`, `COURSE_FK`) VALUES ('S1', 'S1', 'C1');
INSERT INTO `test`.`student` (`id`, `name`, `COURSE_FK`) VALUES ('S2', 'S2', 'C2');
INSERT INTO `test`.`student` (`id`, `name`, `COURSE_FK`) VALUES ('S3', 'S3', 'C1');
```

---

**Query as you given**

```
select st.id ,st.name from student st 
inner join course co on st.COURSE_FK = co.course_id 
where(st.id="S1" and co.course_id="C1");
```

**Result**

```
# id, name
'S1', 'S1'
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OxisK.jpg)

----------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Conclusion : as you put query this error not coming